# ImportError No module named blog

Tags: python, django

I'm working my way through a django tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/ . Following the directions in the template section, I have added:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "F:/firstblog/blog/templates",
```

Which is the full path.

I'm getting the following error output:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named blog
Exception Location: f:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in            import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  f:\python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

My installed apps are:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how to fix this,

Thank you,

Bill

Comment: i would suggest this original tutorial for django. clean and every aspect was mentioned. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ or you can even go for dev.

mind to show us your settings.py and views?

Comment: Thanks, but what dev. mind ? - Bill

Comment: dev = *development version*  
mind = *do you mind*  
 there is point between them

Comment: pls show us your views.py and the whole error trace

Comment: Hi donyor, I think I've fixed this problem with the following comment from the tutorial: "I'm a noob so my terminology might not be correct but basically it nests the settings.py and urls.py for the app inside a folder within the app of the same name. (i.e. FirstBlog>FirstBlog)

This means that we need to change a couple of things in this turorial.

1. When setting up you url pattern you need to put in 'blog.views.home' not 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home'

2. When you change the settings.py file to point django to the app you have installed you need to put in 'blog' not 'FirstBlog.blog'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should also take a look at [the tutorial included](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) in django docs for the parts that may not be covered in the one you found.

you may need to modify `settings.py` and add the `blog` app to `INSTALLED_APPS` to solve the `ImportError`. This is covered in the [*activating models*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) section of the tutorial.

EDIT: here is what seems to be needed to solve the `ImportError` you had.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog', # <------ your app here.
     ...
 }
```

Comment: importerror can also occur if your import is wrong in your views.py. so in settings.py, he did what you propose, i guess

Comment: yes, you are correct, however I suppose settings would be the first place I would check (common mistake, happens to me too).

Comment: The links you gave- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models are no more functional, I see 404 page not found.

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem while working through this tutorial from tutsplus. Like user61629 said, you need to change the url pattern to 'blog.views.home' instead of  'FirstBlog.blog.views.home' and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting comas after each INSTALLED_APPS could also cause a similar error. For example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth'  <----------- No Comma!
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

(May help a beginner like me out there)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple import error. Could be due to either you having not installed the app 'blog' check your settings.py it is installed?

The other issue could be simply an incorrect import path for example

```
from blog.models import Blog
```

Either way it sounds like you should continue reading the docs. I found these video very helpful 
http://hackedexistence.com/project-django.html

Also on another note from your code above don't include full paths like this...

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "F:/firstblog/blog/templates",
```

It can give you a lot of issues later on.

Comment: I don't see the 'blog' app mentioned in the  installed apps ( which I've added above).

Answer (score 0):

It is also a good practice not to use absolute paths like `F:/firstblog/blog/templates` in your project as if you deploy on the server or other people also develop this project they have to change these paths.

Try using `unipath` for this or just `os` module to set paths.

Answer (score 0):

This error might because you rename your Django project after creation. So you have to undo and go back to the name you use to create the Django project or trace the error and update it with the new Django name.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same error because I created app outside of the project.  Check whether your app is in its right directory or not.